# Tomcat hangs shutting down with Spring Integration Java DSL

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm having an issue where trying to gracefully shutdown Tomcat (8) never finishes, due to what appears to be `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` being blocked (or looping) indefinitely.

I've been googling around for solutions, but anything similar I've found hasn't worked. This includes (but is not limited to):

- Using `configureListenerContainer()` to set the taskExecutor of the container
- Using `Messages.queue()` instead of `Messages.direct()`
- Wrapping the `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` in a `CachingConnectionFactory`

A simple Servlet 3.0 example:

```
compile 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.3.6.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jms:4.3.6.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-java-dsl:1.2.1.RELEASE'
```

Initializer:

```
public class ExampleWebApp implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext springContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        springContext.register(ExampleConfig.class);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(springContext));

        final ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addServlet("example", new HttpRequestHandlerServlet());
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/status");
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class ExampleConfig {
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        final ActiveMQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        mqConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL("tcp://host:port");
        mqConnectionFactory.setUserName("----");
        mqConnectionFactory.setPassword("----");

        return mqConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue testQueue() {
        return new ActiveMQQueue("test.queue");
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel testReceiveChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow pushMessageInboundFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory())
                         .destination(testQueue()))
                .log()
                .transform(new JsonToObjectTransformer(TestMessageObject.class))
                .channel(testReceiveChannel())
                .get();
    }

    /** Example message object */
    public static class TestMessageObject {
        private String text;

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(final String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

If I try and stop this via the catalina.sh script (for example, pressing "stop" in Intellij", it never finishes existing. So far the only way I've been able to get shutdown to finish is by "manually" destroying the JmsMessageAdapters on shutdown, via a little helper class:

```
public class JmsMessageListenerContainerLifecycleManager {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsMessageListenerContainerLifecycleManager.class);

    @Autowired
    private List<IntegrationFlow> mIntegrationFlows;

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdownJmsAdapters() throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Checking {} integration flows for JMS message adapters", mIntegrationFlows.size());

        for (IntegrationFlow flow : mIntegrationFlows) {
            if (flow instanceof StandardIntegrationFlow) {
                final StandardIntegrationFlow standardFlow = (StandardIntegrationFlow) flow;

                for (Object component : standardFlow.getIntegrationComponents()) {
                    if (component instanceof JmsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter) {
                        final JmsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter = (JmsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter) component;

                        LOG.info("Destroying JMS adapter {}", adapter.getComponentName());
                        adapter.destroy();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And while that works, it definitely feels like the wrong solution.

Previously I was using XML configuration of spring-integration, and I did not have this problem. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh! This is definitely a bug. And looks like you workaround it properly.

Although consider to destroy any `DisposableBean` there.

I'm adding the fix to the Spring Integration Java DSL. We are going to release the next `1.2.2` just after Spring Integration `4.3.9`.

The Spring Integration `5.0` will have a fix in its `M3` release tomorrow.